# How to provide default values for an empty string in a destructured object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

While performing object destructuring it is possible to provide default values if the key does not exist (i.e. undefinedKey).

If the (string) key does exist, it does not get overwritten (even if empty).

I'm wondering if it's possible to specify an override for an empty string while destructuring. In the example below, I would like `emptyKey` to print `Override for empty key`

```js
const testObject = {
  emptyKey: '',
  filledKey: 'Some Initial Value',
};

const {
  emptyKey = 'Override for empty key',
  filledKey = 'Override for filled key',
  undefinedKey = 'Override for undefined key',
} = testObject;

console.log(emptyKey); //''
console.log(filledKey); //'Some Initial Value'
console.log(undefinedKey); //'Override for undefined key'
```

Comment: I'm trying to define the defaults as early as possible for clarity in a larger function. I know I can just do `||` comparisons where the value is used, but I hope there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it's possible to specify an override for an empty string while destructuring.

No, default values are only considered if the property value is `undefined`. There is no way to override this behavior.

---

As a workaround, you could build your own little default value handler, such as

```js
function defaults(obj, test, defaults) {
  return Object.keys(defaults).reduce((acc, prop) => {
    acc[prop] = test(obj[prop]) ? defaults[prop] : obj[prop];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const testObject = {
  emptyKey: '',
  filledKey: 'Some Initial Value',
};

const {
  emptyKey,
  filledKey,
  undefinedKey,
} = defaults(
  testObject,
  v => v === undefined || v === '',
  {
    emptyKey: 'Override for empty key',
    filledKey: 'Override for filled key',
    undefinedKey:'Override for undefined key',
  }
);

console.log(emptyKey, filledKey, undefinedKey);
```

Not quite as elegant, but flexible.

Comment: Well, that answers that! Much appreciated!